# Progressive web apps and Web socket connections in background

Tags: javascript, websocket, progressive-web-apps

What should be the expected behavior when I add my webpage to home on Android device and my page contains a websocket connection. Should it still gets updates even in the bakground?

Based on my quick demo, it stops receiving updates when in the background. Also i dont have a service worker hooked up yet, its just opens up in full screen as a pwa.

Answer (score 1):

Service Workers live for a limited amount of time (on the order of 5 minutes). They can not maintain persistent connections like WebSockets.

Comment: so if i have a websocket connection on the page, its going to disconnect?

Comment: If you wave a websocket connection on the web page it can stay connected as long as the network and browser let it. In a service worker persistent connections are not allowed.